# (on the phone) It’s Ann you want to speak to. Just one minute, please. I will call her

Tags: phrase-meaning

I don't understand the full meaning of below phrase. Could you help me to understand it?
I suggest that the first sentence is about the speaker name who does a call back, isn't it? On the other side another person says: "Just one minute, please. I will call her." And it means that the call back from Ann is waiting some other person: "she". Am I right?

> (on the phone) It’s Ann you want to speak to. Just one minute, please. I will call her.

Thank you for explanation.

Comment: IMHO this isn't so much about English, it's about an incomplete context. I can ask the same question in German or French...

Comment: Strange answer and strange position to close the post if it has so much useful marks. But OK.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is just my guess.

Suppose that Ann and Betty are sisters and live in the same house. Someone calls that house, and Betty answers the phone. The caller begins speaking to Betty about some matter that ought to be said to Ann instead. Betty tells the caller that he should not say these things to her; he should say them to Ann. "It's Ann you want to speak to."

This could happen because the caller does not know that he should speak to Ann, or because he mistakenly thinks that he is speaking to Ann.

With the next words Betty asks the caller to wait while she brings Ann to the phone. "Just one minute, please. I will call her." She's not calling Ann by making a telephone call; she's just shouting into the hallway "Ann, pick up the telephone, there's a call for you!"

Answer (score 4):

To add to Chaim's answer, this happens often in business settings. Ann had called and ordered a new vacuum cleaner to be delivered. They call the number they were given, to say that they don't have it in red, would she like it in blue.

When the phone rings, Betty answers. The man says, "I'm calling about the vacuum you ordered." Betty replies, "Oh, I didn't order a vacuum, Ann did. It's Ann you want to talk to, I will call her."

Which absolutely means, "I will put down the phone and yell for her to pick it up."

(American English interpretation)